# System of five linear equations but only one is knowing

Tags: linear-algebra

Let suppose that we have system of five linear equations with three unknow $x,y,z$. We know that one of equation of this system is $x+y+z=3$ and $(x,y,z)=(3,0,0),(x,y,z)=(0,3,0)$ are solutions for this system. Is it true that:

1. $(x,y,z)=(0,2,1)$ isn't solution of the system
2. $(x,y,z)=(0,1,2)$ is solution of the system
3. $(x,y,z)=(3,3,0)$ isn't solution of the system
4. $(x,y,z) = (1,2,0)$ is solution of the system

As we can see in 3. we have $3+3+0 = 6 \neq 3$ so $(3,3,0)$ isn't solution of this system. In 4. I can use simple lemma: if $x,y$ are solutions of $AX=b$ then for any $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ $\alpha x + (1- \alpha)y$ is also solution. For $\alpha = \frac{1}{3}$ we have $(1,2,0)=\frac{1}{3}(3,0,0)+\frac{2}{3}(0,3,0)$ so it is solution of this system.

But I have no idea for 1. and 2. I will grateful for your help.

Comment: How did you arrive at the lemma?

Comment: $x,y$ are solutions of $AX=b$ hence $Ax=b$ and $Ay=b$. Thus we have  $A( \alpha x + (1-\alpha)y) = \alpha Ax + (1 - \alpha)Ay = \alpha b + (1- \alpha)b = \alpha b + b - \alpha b = b $.

Comment: Too good! Never saw that one before!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's not enough information in the question to determine (1) and (2).

In one extreme, all five equations could be $x+y+z=3$ (or multiplies thereof), in which case $(0,2,1)$ and $(0,1,2)$ are both solutions.

On the other hand, one of the equations could be $z=0$, which doesn't contradict anything you know. In that case neither $(0,2,1)$ nor $(0,1,2)$ is a solution.